# Cannot link to Crypto++ on Debian due to undefined references

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, debian, crypto++

I have a project that depends on Crypto++ on Debian 8.10. The project has a library (called `common` that uses Crypto++ ) and the executable (`hwinfo`). I'm using Cmake for building purposes.

Here is my library build Cmake:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories()
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")
project(common)
add_library(common ${SOURCES})
find_library(LIBCRYPTOPP cryptopp)
target_link_libraries(common ${LIBCRYPTOPP})
install(TARGETS common 
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib)
```

And my executable Cmake file:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(../common)
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")
project(hwinfo)
add_executable(hwinfo ${SOURCES})
find_library(LIBCOMMON common PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib)
find_library(LIBCRYPTOPP cryptopp)
message(STATUS "CRYPTO LIBRARY ===>" ${LIBCRYPTOPP})
message(STATUS "MY COMMON LIBRARY ===>" ${LIBCOMMON})
target_link_libraries(hwinfo ${LIBCRYPTOPP} ${LIBCOMMON})
install(TARGETS hwinfo 
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../bin)
```

From the diagnostic messages in the executable Cmake (`message (STATUS...`)):

```
-- CRYPTO LIBRARY ===>/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a
-- MY COMMON LIBRARY ===>/home/myself/dev/common/lib/libcommon.a
```

So, the libraries are being found. Here are the errors I'm getting on compilation. I've cropped some errors otherwise I wouldn't be able to post, but seen that all crypto calls are undefined:

```
...    
[ 64%] Linking CXX executable hwinfo
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `common::Encryptor::encrypt(std::string)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text+0x2a6): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::CipherModeFinalTemplate_ExternalCipher<CryptoPP::CBC_Encryption>::CipherModeFinalTemplate_ExternalCipher(CryptoPP::BlockCipher&, unsigned char const*, int)'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate<std::string>::StringSinkTemplate(std::string&)'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::StreamTransformationFilter(CryptoPP::StreamTransformation&, CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation*, CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::BlockPaddingScheme, bool)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `common::Encryptor::decrypt(std::string)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text+0x477): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::CipherModeFinalTemplate_ExternalCipher<CryptoPP::CBC_Decryption>::CipherModeFinalTemplate_ExternalCipher(CryptoPP::BlockCipher&, unsigned char const*, int)'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text+0x4a5): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate<std::string>::StringSinkTemplate(std::string&)'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text+0x4cd): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::StreamTransformationFilter(CryptoPP::StreamTransformation&, CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation*, CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::BlockPaddingScheme, bool)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::~SimpleKeyingInterface()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP21SimpleKeyingInterfaceD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP21SimpleKeyingInterfaceD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::~BufferedTransformation()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformationD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformationD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformationD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformationD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SimpleKeyingInterface()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP21SimpleKeyingInterfaceC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP21SimpleKeyingInterfaceC5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::StreamTransformation::~StreamTransformation()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20StreamTransformationD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP20StreamTransformationD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::StreamTransformation'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockOrientedCipherModeBase::Resynchronize(unsigned char const*, int)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP27BlockOrientedCipherModeBase13ResynchronizeEPKhi[_ZN8CryptoPP27BlockOrientedCipherModeBase13ResynchronizeEPKhi]+0x23): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::ThrowIfInvalidIVLength(int)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::Filter::~Filter()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP6FilterD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP6FilterD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Filter'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP6FilterD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP6FilterD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Filter'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::FilterWithBufferedInput::~FilterWithBufferedInput()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP23FilterWithBufferedInputD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP23FilterWithBufferedInputD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::FilterWithBufferedInput'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP23FilterWithBufferedInputD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP23FilterWithBufferedInputD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::FilterWithBufferedInput'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char, CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, false> >::~SecBlock()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SecBlockIhNS_20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb0EEEED2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SecBlockIhNS_20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb0EEEED5Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, false>::deallocate(void*, unsigned long)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char, CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, false> >::New(unsigned long)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SecBlockIhNS_20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb0EEEE3NewEm[_ZN8CryptoPP8SecBlockIhNS_20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb0EEEE3NewEm]+0x32): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, false>::reallocate(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockTransformation::BlockTransformation()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP19BlockTransformationC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP19BlockTransformationC5Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Algorithm::Algorithm(bool)'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP19BlockTransformationC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP19BlockTransformationC5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::BlockTransformation'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockTransformation::~BlockTransformation()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP19BlockTransformationD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP19BlockTransformationD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::BlockTransformation'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base::Base()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael4BaseC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael4BaseC5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael4BaseC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael4BaseC5Ev]+0x2c): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base::~Base()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael4BaseD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael4BaseD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael4BaseD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael4BaseD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::Enc()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncC5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncC5Ev]+0x2b): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::~Enc()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)0, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc>::BlockCipherFinal(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEC2EPKhm[_ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEC5EPKhm]+0x3b): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::g_nullNameValuePairs'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEC2EPKhm[_ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEC5EPKhm]+0x4f): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockOrientedCipherModeBase::~BlockOrientedCipherModeBase()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP27BlockOrientedCipherModeBaseD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP27BlockOrientedCipherModeBaseD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::BlockOrientedCipherModeBase'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP27BlockOrientedCipherModeBaseD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP27BlockOrientedCipherModeBaseD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::BlockOrientedCipherModeBase'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::CBC_Encryption::~CBC_Encryption()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP14CBC_EncryptionD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP14CBC_EncryptionD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::CBC_Encryption'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP14CBC_EncryptionD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP14CBC_EncryptionD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::CBC_Encryption'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::Dec()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3DecC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3DecC5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3DecC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3DecC5Ev]+0x2b): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::~Dec()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3DecD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3DecD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3DecD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3DecD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)1, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec>::BlockCipherFinal(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEC2EPKhm[_ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEC5EPKhm]+0x3b): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::g_nullNameValuePairs'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEC2EPKhm[_ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEC5EPKhm]+0x4f): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::CBC_Decryption::~CBC_Decryption()':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP14CBC_DecryptionD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP14CBC_DecryptionD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::CBC_Decryption'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP14CBC_DecryptionD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP14CBC_DecryptionD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::CBC_Decryption'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, true>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEmPKv]+0x40): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedAllocate(unsigned long)'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEmPKv]+0x4e): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::UnalignedAllocate(unsigned long)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, true>::deallocate(void*, unsigned long)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE10deallocateEPvm[_ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE10deallocateEPvm]+0x39): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedDeallocate(void*)'
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE10deallocateEPvm[_ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE10deallocateEPvm]+0x47): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::UnalignedDeallocate(void*)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE]+0x48): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE]+0x78): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::GetNextIV(CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator&, unsigned char*)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE]+0x88): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE]+0xa0): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE]+0xa8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE]+0xf0): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE]+0x100): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BlockTransformation::OptimalDataAlignment() const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEE]+0x120): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE]+0x48): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE]+0x78): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::GetNextIV(CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator&, unsigned char*)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE]+0x88): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE]+0xa0): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE]+0xa8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE]+0xe8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE]+0xf8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BlockTransformation::OptimalDataAlignment() const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEES4_EE]+0x118): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0x48): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0x78): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::GetNextIV(CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator&, unsigned char*)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0x88): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0xa0): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0xa8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0xf0): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0x100): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BlockTransformation::OptimalDataAlignment() const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEE]+0x120): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE]+0x48): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE]+0x78): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::GetNextIV(CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator&, unsigned char*)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE]+0x88): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE]+0xa0): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE]+0xa8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE]+0xe8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE]+0xf8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BlockTransformation::OptimalDataAlignment() const'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEES4_EE]+0x118): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
   Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncC2ERKS1_[_ZN8CryptoPP8Rijndael3EncC5ERKS1_]+0x36): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cpp/hwinfo/CMakeFiles/hwinfo.dir/build.make:85: recipe for target 'cpp/hwinfo/hwinfo' failed
make[2]: *** [cpp/hwinfo/hwinfo] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:167: recipe for target 'cpp/hwinfo/CMakeFiles/hwinfo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [cpp/hwinfo/CMakeFiles/hwinfo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've no idea of what is causing that.

Why is my Crypto++ library not being loaded to resolve the symbols as they are explicitly declared on my Cmake file?

---

***EDIT***: After inverting the libraries order, as follows:

```cmake
target_link_libraries(hwinfo ${LIBCOMMON} ${LIBCRYPTOPP})
```

I'm getting fewer error messages, but still undefined symbols as follows:

```
[71%] Linking CXX executable hwinfo
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)0, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc>::BlockCipherFinal(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEC2EPKhm[_ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEC5EPKhm]+0x3b): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::g_nullNameValuePairs'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)1, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec>::BlockCipherFinal(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEC2EPKhm[_ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEC5EPKhm]+0x3b): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::g_nullNameValuePairs'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12CBC_ModeBaseE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12CBC_ModeBaseE]+0x128): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StreamTransformation::ProcessLastBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP14CipherModeBaseE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP14CipherModeBaseE]+0x100): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StreamTransformation::ProcessLastBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)'
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP15SymmetricCipherE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP15SymmetricCipherE]+0xe8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StreamTransformation::ProcessLastBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cpp/hwinfo/CMakeFiles/hwinfo.dir/build.make:85: recipe for target 'cpp/hwinfo/hwinfo' failed
make[2]: *** [cpp/hwinfo/hwinfo] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:167: recipe for target 'cpp/hwinfo/CMakeFiles/hwinfo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [cpp/hwinfo/CMakeFiles/hwinfo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Also see [Noloader | Crypto++ Cmake](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake) on GitHub. We were trying to support Cmake but it was causing too many problems so we spun it off to a separate project.

Answer (score 1):

Order matters! If library A depends on library B, then library A must come *before* library B when linking. So the simple solution is to change the order in which you link your "common" library and the cryptopp library.

Also note that since you apparently create a static library, you don't actually *link* anything when creating the library. So the `target_link_libraries` command is useless for the library, as your project is currently set up.

My suggestion is that you link the two `CMakeLists.txt` files together, so the main executable `CMakeLists.txt` file uses the library `CMakeLists.txt` file (for example using the `add_subdirectory` command). Then you first of all don't need to install the library, and you could make `COMMON` depend on `CRYPTOPP` and CMake would link in correct order.

Comment: @SPD, thanks for the post, but sorry, but I can't get your point. `target_link_libraries(hwinfo ${LIBCRYPTOPP} ${LIBCOMMON})` puts it in the correct order as far as I know, as COMMON depends on CRYPTOPP. Joining the two CMakeLists.txt won't help also, as I cannot do it (this is a subset of a bigger project with many CMakeLists involved). Please point out if you see any mistake on my ordering....

Comment: @Mendes `LIBCOMMON` depends on `LIBCRYPTOPP`, therefore `LIBCOMMON` must be first.

Comment: Exchanged the position, but no changes on result. `target_link_libraries(hwinfo ${LIBCOMMON} ${LIBCRYPTOPP})`... Same errors....

Comment: @Mendes Time to make a clean and *verbose* build, of both your library and executable, with lots of warnings enabled when building. See what commands are being run to build your library and executable. See if you can replicate your problem using manual building, and then attempt to make your manual build work. Try to minimize the everything, scale back to make it work, and then add one little piece at a time. If it breaks then you know when and where the problem is, and can concentrate on that part to solve your problem.

Comment: Scaling down is what I've done. `common` has simple calls to `cryptopp` and `hwinfo` is a simple program that calls `common`... Ths issue is related to linking and I really need to fix my `cmake` files. Check my EDIT, but inverting the messages are fewer, but shows the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this:

> I have a project that depends on cryptopp on Debian 8.10

And this:

```
../../../lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP15SymmetricCipherE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP15SymmetricCipherE]+0xe8):
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StreamTransformation::ProcessLastBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And this:

```
-- CRYPTO LIBRARY ===>/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a
```

It looks like you have two copies of the Crypo++ library and you are mixing and matching them.

I think the easiest/best fix is to run the following commands. They remove your copy so you use Debian's copy.

```bash
rm -rf /usr/local/include/cryptopp
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/*cryptopp*
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/cryptest*
rm -rf /usr/local/share/cryptopp
```

---

The reason I think its a problem is because `ProcessLastBlock` now returns a `size_t`. That change happened at Crypto++ 6.0. The change was needed for authenticated encryption modes like OCB. OCB handles padding of the last block itself, so it needed a way to specify how much of the provided buffer was used.

Crypto++ 5.6.3 and earlier used `ProcessLastBlock` that returned `void`. There was a tight coupling of a block cipher mode and an explicit requirement the last block was always a full block size. But like I said, that did not hold as we started adding additional modes of operation.

Also see the head notes in [`filters.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/filters.cpp#L694) and the function `StreamTransformationFilter::LastPut`:

```cxx
// This block is new to StreamTransformationFilter. It somewhat of a hack and was added
//  for OCB mode; see GitHub Issue 515. The rub with OCB is, its a block cipher and the
//  last block size can be 0. However, "last block = 0" is not the 0 predacted in the
//  original code. In the orginal code 0 means "nothing special" so DEFAULT_PADDING is
//  applied. OCB's 0 literally means a final block size can be 0 or non-0; and no padding
//  is needed in either case because OCB has its own scheme (see handling of P_* and A_*).
// Stream ciphers have policy objects to convey how to operate the cipher. The Crypto++
//  framework operates well when MinLastBlockSize() is 1. However, it did not appear to
//  cover the OCB case either because we can't stream OCB. It needs full block sizes. In
//  response we hacked a IsLastBlockSpecial(). When true StreamTransformationFilter
//  defers to the mode for processing of the last block.
// The behavior supplied when IsLastBlockSpecial() will likely have to evolve to capture
//  more complex cases from different authenc modes. I suspect it will have to change
//  from a simple bool to something that conveys more information, like "last block
//  no padding" or "custom padding applied by cipher".
// In some respect we have already hit the need for more information. For example, OCB
//  calculates the checksum on the cipher text at the same time, so we don't need the
//  disjoint behavior of calling "EncryptBlock" followed by a separate "AuthenticateBlock".
//  Additional information may allow us to avoid the two spearate calls.
```

---

And to reiterate from [Linux | Distribution Package](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Linux#Distribution_Package) on the wiki:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie)
Release:        8.10
Codename:       jessie

$ apt-cache search libcrypto++
...
libcrypto++-dev - General purpose cryptographic library - C++ development
libcrypto++-doc - General purpose cryptographic library - documentation
libcrypto++-utils - General purpose cryptographic library - utilities and data files
libcrypto++9 - General purpose cryptographic library - shared library
libcrypto++9-dbg - General purpose cryptographic library - debug symbols
```

So you need `libcrypto++9`, `libcrypto++-dev` and possibly `libcrypto++9-dbg`.